# Getting address by google maps

Tags: jsp, google-maps

I need to get the address by pointing some location using google maps, and also save it, so I can show the location in some other time. I´ve been reading about it, but I dont understand too much. DO I have to save the address, the latitude and longitude ?, or do I just need the first one? I 'd appreciate some examples. I am using jsp .